# Remove the first word in my sql statement

Tags: cursor, trim, sql-function

I have a function in Microsoft SQL that creates auto sql lines, a (Querybuilder). In this case I have this line in one of my Cursors That looks something like this:

```
  set @Query = @Query + ' AND ('+ (case when(@CountryDelivery = 1) then 'Delivery' else     'pickup' end) +'.CountryUK '+ (case(@CountryExcl) when 1 then ' <> ''' else ' = ''' end) + @country + ''')'
```

This will make my result look something like:
"AND (country = 'USA') AND (Country = 'Canada') ......"ETC, all depends how many countries the user stores in his datatable.

My challenge is that I want the "AND" statement to be removed at the start of the Query but not if the user add more countries.

This is my full function:

```
SET @Query = @Query + ' ('  
declare Accountring_Country1Cursor Cursor for 
        select Country, Exclude, IsDelivery, ID from dbo.Accounting_Country1 where Service_ID = @Service_ID        
OPEN Accountring_Country1Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM Accountring_Country1Cursor 
INTO @country, @CountryExcl, @CountryDelivery, @country_ID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
set @Query = @Query + ' AND ('+ (case when(@CountryDelivery = 1) then 'Delivery'     else 'pickup' end) +'.CountryUK '+ (case(@CountryExcl) when 1 then ' <> ''' else ' = ''' end) + @country + ''')'    
    FETCH NEXT FROM Accountring_Country1Cursor 
INTO @country, @CountryExcl, @CountryDelivery,@country_ID
END 
CLOSE Accountring_Country1Cursor
DEALLOCATE Accountring_Country1Cursor 
SET @Query = @Query + ') '              
RETURN @Query

     END
```

Comment: What about combining the where clause in a different variable first, where you'd initialize it with a value of '(1 = 1)'? Then you'd get '(1 = 1) AND (someothercondition)' which is just syntactically fine, and which should be removed by the query plan optimizer anyway.

Comment: Hi! I don't quit understand what you are trying to say.
But I forgot to mention that my functions name is FunctionTest()
and maybe i can do the trim on the FunctionTest somehow to remove the first word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @filter varchar(max);
set @filter = '(1 = 1)';

declare Accountring_Country1Cursor Cursor for select Country, Exclude, IsDelivery, ID from dbo.Accounting_Country1 where Service_ID = @Service_ID        
OPEN Accountring_Country1Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM Accountring_Country1Cursor INTO @country, @CountryExcl, @CountryDelivery, @country_ID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    set @filter = @filter + ' AND ('+ (case when(@CountryDelivery = 1) then 'Delivery'     else 'pickup' end) +'.CountryUK '+ (case(@CountryExcl) when 1 then ' <> ''' else ' = ''' end) + @country + ''')'    
    FETCH NEXT FROM Accountring_Country1Cursor INTO @country, @CountryExcl, @CountryDelivery,@country_ID
END 

CLOSE Accountring_Country1Cursor
DEALLOCATE Accountring_Country1Cursor 

SET @Query = @Query + '(' + @filter + ') '              
RETURN @Query
```

Basically, the default value for the filter is *true*. Then you can always add a new ' AND (something)', because it will be valid SQL. And after you're done building the filter, you just append it to your `@Query` variable, all at once.

Or, in a more straightforward way, you can just take a substring of your final query:

```
set @Query = '(' + substring(@Query, 4, len(@Query))
```

Or, slightly more complicated but more versatile:

```
set @Query = substring(@Query, 0, 1) + substring(@Query, 4, len(@Query))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for respond! I will put it in my code and get back to you! :-)

Comment: And please, make sure you actually need to build the query this way, and that you properly validate the input data - this could be exploited to inject any harmful SQL if you don't validate @Country for example. Ignore me if you're filling the Accounting_Country1 table manually (out of the users reach at least).

Comment: When I use the code, It's not working Maybe ill post the whole query for you, could the problem be im using nested cursors??

Comment: This is the full Function http://pastie.org/8528258
As you can see ther country on top which starts with AND and it close at the bottom because it has nested cursors, I hope you can help!!

Comment: @MishMish: You probably forgot to add the `@Filter` value to `@Query`. Or you might have to declare the `@Filter` variable before the first loop. What kind of error are you getting? A syntax error? Or the wrong query? What's in `@Filter` and `@Query`?

Comment: All I had to add below my Query Line is this :
 set @Query = substring(@Query, 4 , len(@Query))
It removes the first 4! but is it possible to skip the first charchter and remove the next 3??

Comment: Why? You know the first character, just do `set @Query = ' ' + substring(@Query, 4, len(@Query))`. Or if you don't know it, just get the first using substring (`substring(@Query, 0, 1)`) and add this to the beginning of the other substring.

Comment: the reason is if u look into my code I have 2 "((" before my country data starts and it ends with "))" This way I can add mutiple postals, adrid's etc for more then one country.
My problem as stated earlier I have "(AND(Country = 'USA' AND other data))" As you see I want the AND removed from "(AND(". I know it's very complicated to explain, Im very bad to explain stuff sry for that :)

Comment: If you put the code I wrote in your comment I will accept it as correct answer, just update it mate